# How to group by with NULL values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-server-2012

What would be the simplest way to group by when  NULL values?

```
declare @MyTable Table (ID int, Name varchar(50),Coverage varchar(50), Premium money)
insert into @MyTable values (1,'Robert', 'AutoBI', 100),
                            (1,'Robert', NULL, 300),
                            (2,'Neill','AutoBIPD',150),
                            (2,'Neill','AutoBI',200),
                            (3,'Kim', 'Collision',50),
                            (3,'Kim',NULL,100),
                            (4,'Rick','AutoBI',70),
                            (5,'Lukasz','Comprehensive',50),
                            (5,'Lukasz','NULL',25)

select ID, 
        Name, 
        Coverage, 
        sum(Premium) as Premium 
from @MyTable
group by ID
        ,Name   
        ,Premium
        ,Coverage
```

The outcome looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is NULL value for name 'Robert'.
How can I have summed premium ($400) and only one line without NULL Coverage?

But I need to make it look like this:

[image]

I cannot use MAX() function in this case.

Comment: What if you get row with `2 Neill NULL 100` then where it should be added? `AutoBI`/`AutoBIPD` or both?

Comment: Are AutoBIPD and AutoBI the only possible values for Coverage?

Comment: AutoBIPD and AutoBI are not the only possible values for Coverage

Comment: There are should not be `2 Neill NULL 100`. Always gonna be at least one NOT NULL Coverage

Comment: @Oleg Please read once again. You want to add null value to some specific group. Which one? If you have rows `2 Neill AutoBI 200; 2 Neill AutoBIPD 150; 2 Neill NULL 100` then how do you want combine `NULL`?

Comment: In this case I would add NULL value to Robert group.  It would be 1 line :              `1 Robert AutoBI 400`

Comment: @oleg Please specify how code should work when you have more than **single** value. It is crucial to get stable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes that `NULL` will be grouped to one "random" `NOT NULL` value within `ID/Name`. If more than single value is poissible then this query won't return stable result sets between executions:

```
select ID, 
        Name, 
        ISNULL(m1.Coverage, sub.Coverage) AS Coverage,
        sum(Premium) as Premium
FROM  @MyTable m1
cross apply (SELECT TOP 1 m2.Coverage FROM @MyTable m2 WHERE Coverage IS NOT NULL 
             AND m1.ID = m2.ID AND m1.Name = m2.Name) sub
group by ID
        ,Name   
        ,ISNULL(m1.Coverage, sub.Coverage);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/LSJNIM87318)**